# Find a continuous function , Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}_+$ which does not tend to zero

Tags: examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity, riemann-integration

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous and Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}_+$ (i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_0^x f(s)ds$ exists and is finite), then $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Thus, I want to find an example of a continuous function, Riemann integrable on $\mathbb{R}_+$ which does not tend to zero.

Clearly, the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ should not exist.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this question has been on this site before, and I'm pretty sure I answered it

Comment: It has bumps. Tall, skinny bumps.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi(x)$ denote the bump function used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), and define
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x)\, dx.$$
The function
$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \psi(2^n(x-n))$$
is clearly continuous. It is also Riemann integrable, because
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^x f(x) \, dx = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-n} I = I.$$
However $f(x)$ does not converge when $x\to \infty$.

Comment: If the function is uniformly continuous, then the limit is zero. I think that he wanted to know why the "uniformly" is necessary.